# Using SQL to create table joins in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm REALLY new to SQL and I'm really struggling with all but the simplest of joins - especially in MS Access.

At this stage, all I want to do is create a query from two tables: 'tblUsers', with columns 'UserID' and 'User', and 'tblPayments' with columns 'PaymentID', 'User' and 'Authoriser'. I want my query to contain all of this data and also to have columns 'UserID' and 'AuthoriserID', both of these ID numbers being taken from 'tblUsers', but clearly one will relate to the User and one to the authoriser.

I'm sure this is far more simple than I'm making it but how should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can join the same tables multiple times, you just need a unique alias for every extra join past the first. e.g. `select ... from foo join bar on ... join bar AS extra ...`.

Comment: the below should work?

SELECT Payments.ID, Payments.User, Users.UserID, Payments.Authoriser, Users_1.UserID
FROM (Users INNER JOIN Payments ON Users.User = Payments.User) INNER JOIN Users AS Users_1 ON Payments.Authoriser = Users_1.User;)

Comment: looks like it, though, as usual, access's bracketing requirements give me a major headache.

Comment: I'm really struggling with access full stop!

Comment: Could you could give some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @MarcB I'm downloading MS SQL Express already, just waiting for my majorly slow internet connection and thought I'd use Access whilst the dl was going. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in query designer drag tblUsers in twice  and tblPayments in once.  drag the userID from users to user in payments  drag userID from the OTHER users table to authoriser then grab the * from each table and put in your query result window.

Comment: Have you tried using the Access Designer (QBE Grid)? IT abstracts you from having to understand the nuisances of Access' implementation of SQL. It is quite different than SQL Server. If you use the QBE a few times, you may find it easier than coding the SQL by hand.

Comment: @MarcB How could this SQL query be written in MS SQL Express?

Comment: mostly the same, just not needing the `()`.

Comment: @MarcB Apparently the syntax is incorrect?

`SELECT Payments.[PaymentID], Payments.User, Users.UserID, Payments.Authoriser, Users_1.UserID
FROM Users INNER JOIN Payments ON Users.User = Payments.User INNER JOIN Users AS Users_1 ON Payments.Authoriser = Users_1.User;`

Comment: looks ok to me, but my meatspace parser (e.g. brain) is pretty fried at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that there are minor differences in syntax between SQL server SQL and Access SQL. While in most cases a query written in Access will function normally on SQL server, the opposite is less true because of the shortcuts often used on SQL server (example: dropping the 'INNER' from the joins and the 'AS' when using an alias.)

Access:

```
SELECT tblUsers.UserID, 
tblUsers.User, 
tblPayments.paymentID, 
tblUsers.User AS  Authoriser, 
tblUsers_1.UserID AS AuthoriserID

FROM (tblPayments 
INNER JOIN tblUsers AS tblUsers_1 
  ON tblPayments.AuthorisorID = tblUsers_1.UserID) 
INNER JOIN tblUsers 
  ON tblPayments.userID = tblUsers.UserID;
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT tblUsers.UserID, 
tblUsers.User, 
tblPayments.paymentID, 
tblUsers.User Authoriser, 
tblUsers_1.UserID AuthoriserID

FROM tblPayments 
JOIN tblUsers tblUsers_1 
  ON tblPayments.AuthorisorID = tblUsers_1.UserID 
JOIN tblUsers 
  ON tblPayments.userID = tblUsers.UserID;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I managed to work out the syntactical difference later that day but your answer was extremely helpful in helping me understand best practice in terms of layout too.