# How to include date & time from two table into one query or report in access

Tags: ms-access, join

I would like to ask how can I make a report in MS access that includes Date In, Time in & Date Out, Time Out which is coming form two different table.

I have Time In table having these information :

```
EmpID, Name, Job, Section, Date In, Time In
```

and I have Time Out table having these information :

```
EmpID, Name, Job, Section, Date Out, Time Out
```

I want to create a report that will show:

```
EmpID, Name, Job, Section, Date in, Time In, Date Out, Time Out
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL to create table joins in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358561/using-sql-to-create-table-joins-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to study an intro to SQL. Anyway:

```
Select 
    [Time In].EmpID, 
    [Time In].Name, 
    [Time In].Job, 
    [Time In].Section, 
    [Time In].[Date In], 
    [Time In].[Time In],
    [Time Out].[Date Out],
    [Time Out].[Time Out]
From
    [Time In]
Inner Join
    [Time Out]
    On [Time In].EmpID = [Time Out].EmpID
```

Comment: You may need the table names as shown. The syntax is correct.